# Could not resolve property: X of: Y Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, alias, criteria

I have 1 entity which attributes are other entities, an example:

```
@Entity
public class Visite implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="agent_uid")
    private Agent agent;
}

@Entity
public class Agent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer uniqueId;

    private String displayName;
}
```

Well, when I try to apply restrictions to "Visite" about "Agent" fields, I get the error: "Could not resolve property: X of: Visite" where X is the field. I tries using creatingAlias but it doesn't work.

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Visita.class).createAlias("pdv", "pdv").
                    createAlias("pdv.address", "address").
                    createAlias("pdv.category", "category").
                    createAlias("agent", "agent").
                    createAlias("visiteType", "visiteType", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN).
                    createAlias("reason", "reason", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN).
                    add(Restrictions.eq("agent.uniqueId", agentId));
```

In this example, the agent.uniqueId works, but agent.displayName doesn't work, for example.
Another failure I get it's I get the results of the query 4 times, I get all duplicates, I don't know why.

Thank you

Comment: Just a hint: translating your fields to English makes their semantics more understandable for non Spanish speaking people.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize. Thank you ;)

Comment: @Juanjo, your question is not clear. What are `Visita, Visitador` fields? Also you are creating alias for fields that do not exist in your entity like address, category etc. Finally it is not clear what is working and what is not working and what exception you are getting (show the stacktrace of exception if you have any). Please edit your question and give complete details.

Comment: I updated the question with translation. Sorry, I didn't put more code to make clear the question. If I want to make restrictions with agent, agent.uniqueId works but agent.displayName doesn't, for example

Comment: @Juanjo, still it is not clear when you say it is not working then what it means? getting some errors? please check the query generated by hibernate and see if there is any issue with that.

Comment: @Chaitanya yes, as I said I get the error "Could not resolve property: X of: Visite", where X is the field I try to use, for example displayName